# openssl, sign (sha1) a message AND make s/mime

Tags: openssl, mime, sha1

I'm new to openssl and all this crypto-stuff and would need a little help.

I need to sign a message (digest sha1) AND put it in a mime-part.

a) digest and signing it I get with:

```
openssl sha1 -sign mycert.pem -passin pass:1234  data > signed_sha1
```

b) mime and signing (but the whole message instead of only digest) I get with:

```
openssl smime -sign -in data -signer mypfx.pfx -passin pass:1234 > mime
```

So, a) gives me a digest and a signatur of it but not all as final result in a MIME

and

b) gives me a MIME but a signature of the whole message an not onyl of the SHA1.

If I combine a) and b) I am afrait of double signing (sign my signed-sha1 from a) in b) again) 
and I dont know how to make with openssl just the mime-stuff (in b) to avoid double-signing) without -sign.

If I only make the sha1 in a) without signin I am not sure if I can simply concatinate my data-file with the result of a) and b) will give me the right result.

thx for help!

chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by myself. Problem was a corrupt mime-message.